# Problem with using icons in phonegap application

Tags: android, windows, cordova, svg, mobile

I've tried to use svg in cordova aplication. 
I tried to use different ways and technics. But unfortunately, they don't work.
PhoneGap Developer application shows empty space or nothing. 
Can I use SVG in Cordova app?
Does it depend on the platform? (unfortunately, the documentation doesn't cover this question.) I test my app in windows phone 10.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem using [iconic](https://useiconic.com/open/).

1. Download iconic.
2. Just add all font files to your project.
3. Add a link to your index.html file `<link href="/yourFolder/font/css/open-iconic.css" rel="stylesheet">`
4. Check path at the bottom of the open-iconic.css file.
5. Add the element to your document object model. `<span class="oi" data-glyph="icon-name" title="icon name" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
6. Done!